# Ldap differences between {crypt} and {CRYPT}

Tags: hash, ldap

I recently stumbled upon some password entries in LDAP marked with the `{crypt}` scheme. Since all recent entries are `{CRYPT}`, I was wondering what the differences between the hash algorithms are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are talking about an OpenLDAP server. It *seems* that OpenLDAP follows the format specified in [RFC 2307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307#section-5.3), where we see:

> ```
>     passwordvalue          = schemeprefix encryptedpassword
> ```

```
    schemeprefix           = "{" scheme "}"
    scheme                 = "crypt" / "md5" / "sha" / altscheme
    altscheme              = "x-" keystring
    encryptedpassword      = encrypted password
```

which would indicate that the "correct" scheme names are in lowercase, not uppercase. Since existing, deployed servers use uppercase names, it is probable that the name is not case-sensitive. In that sense, "{crypt}" and "{CRYPT}" would be equivalent and designate the same algorithm.

Since RFC 2307 is both old and marked "experimental", there is no guarantee here. I suggest that you try it out by taking one "{crypt}" entry and changing it to "{CRYPT}", and see if the user can still log in.